# Is /proc folder and process details really exists on hard drive

Tags: kernel, memory, hard-disk, proc, process-management

I am a little bit confused about `/proc` directory. Each process frequently updating its state, memory info, progress etc in their process.

My question is that the /proc directory keeps the memory or writes on harddrive each information.

What I believe that It frequently updating the information it takes IO operations and it no further uses when computer restart so it might be in the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/proc` directory itself exists as an empty directory on the hard drive. It's contents, however, are added by the kernel without touching the disk. If you try to access `/proc` before it is mounted (say, booting your system with nothing but a shell with `init=/bin/sh`), it will be empty.

You can replicate `/proc` on any directory with `mount -t proc proc /path/to/directory`.

Just like `ext4`, `fat32`, etc., `proc` is a filesystems. (It is referred to as a pseudo filesystem because it cannot actually be used for storing files. If you try to do so, even as root, it will not work.) There are 'real' filesystems like `proc` that don't write to the disk, say `ramfs`/`tmpfs`. These filesystems don't actually write their files the disk, rather keeping them in the system ram. (If it isn't already there, I recommend adding the line `tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw 0 0` to your `/etc/fstab`  so that temporary files written to `/tmp` don't actually get written to your disk.)

There are a few other pseudo filesystems, like `sysfs` on `/sys` and `devtmpfs` on `/dev`. (`/dev` is slightly different. It isn't maintained by the kernel, and `devtmpfs` isn't *always* mounted over `/dev`, sometimes block files are written directory to the disk.)